# Why doesn't my dropdown menu work?

Tags: html

> My bootstrap dropdown menu appeared when the screen was shrunk, but when I clicked on it, nothing showed. I also added jQuery library, not sure if it was added the right way though.
>   Please help! My html code is below...

```
   <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Personal website</title>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css@3.5.2/animate.min.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
      <body>
        <header>
        <nav id ="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class= "container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <div class="navbar-brand">
                <a href="index.html"><h1 class="animated infinite swing">MY NAME</h1></a>
              </div> <!--End of navbar brand-->

              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div> <!-- End of navbar-header-->

              <div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
               <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                  <a href="#main-content">
                   Home</a>
                </li> <!--End of li 1-->
                <li>
                  <a href="#about-me">
                    About Me</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#project-tiles">
                    My Projects</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#contact-info"> Contact Me </a>
                </li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!--End collapsable-nav-->
          </div> <!--End header-nav-->
        </nav>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a random header tag at the start of line 14 with no closing tag.

Removing that opener I was able to achieve the result of drop down when in the smaller view

Comment: I had the header closing tag in my code editor. I just forgot to add it here. Sorry about that. But it still didn't work. When I clicked on that collapsed menu, nothing showed up!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you put your bootstrap.min.js correctly, can you replace it with `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` to see if it works.